# How to Manage location of a Dynamic Download Link

Tags: android, c++, qt, web

I have a small Android application I'm doing for fun. One of the main parts of the application is the ability to download a document from a certain website. However, the link for the download will change frequently and I'd like to have some way to manage which link the application downloads. With little experience, the first thought I had would be an XML file I could download and parse with the necessary links to the documents (note that the documents aren't sensitive and people got to the XML file it'd be worthless). Really it could be any human editable format on the web server.

Some additional info is that I'm using C++ (Qt) for my Android application, but I don't really think this is going to limit it too much. It's mainly the best way to store a dynamic link location. The other, more far-fetched idea I had would be a TcpServer that updates the address, but I feel that's a bit overkill.

Comment: Downloading an XML file containing the information seems reasonable to me.

Comment: @JBentley Yeah, that's my first thought. I just have a strange feeling there is something better. After researching for a few hours, I couldn't find anything anywhere near my specific case.

Comment: It's a fairly common problem (e.g. an application which downloads a list of download mirrors, or a game which downloads a list of available servers), and since security is not an issue, I don't see a need to over-engineer it. Linux package managers typically take this approach, for example, for updating the list of available packages.

Comment: XML is nice because it is a well standardized mark-up language for structured information, and there are plenty of parsing libraries available in C++, so you do not need to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Thanks guys. I knew about the Linux repository, and I know I could probably use other formats but I figured either JSON or XML would be best, and I'm more comfortable with XML. It'll be good if I decide to switch over to Java later, or even another language.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out in the comments, XML on the webserver is a good solution. Now when I update the links in the XML file, the download link will change dynamically in the Android app (or other places). This is okay because XML is standardized and security isn't an issue.

Thanks for the help and second opinions!